# Can I delete a question of mine if I find it very trivial?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

I feel my questions have been very trivial sometimes. Can I go ahead and delete them?

Comment: That really depends on the question. If they're that trivial, why'd you post it in the first place?

Comment: @Cerbrus : Because when I was working through my problem I couldn't find an answer to it. So I posted that question here. However, I feel now had I given more time to it, I would have figured out the solution.

Comment: If it might be useful to at least one other person, don't.

Comment: @AndrewArnold: Thank you Andrew for an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, unless it hurts someone else.  For example, if I spend my time trying to help you by answering your question, I have wasted my time if you delete it  There are automatic checks that will prevent this from happening.

Do note, however, that deleted questions are included in the autoban algorithm.  So if you delete a lot of your own stuff you might get postbanned.

But no matter what, please don't post questions unless it is the last resort.  Wasting people's time with questions that are easily answered is kinda rude.

Comment: Questions that are difficult for someone might be easy for someone else. And then those people downvote the questions sometimes.

Comment: I find it rude if I spent time on an answer and the question is deleted. It might upset me so much, that I'll put you on a personal, non-answer list ;).

Comment: @user3527975 Sometimes they do.  And you have to deal.  But I think most people won't downvote easy questions that you find are hard if you make the effort to clearly state your problem and show what steps you have taken to solve it and why these failed.  e.g., "I searched on google" doesn't cut it.